# How to read xls sheet using Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I am working on a project. I need to read a xls file using Python. The intention is I don't want to put hard corded values in my coding, instead I want to read it from the xls sheet, so that if values get changes due to upgrade in xls sheet, it won't affect my coding.

Comment: [Have you searched your exact question online?](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+read+xls+sheet+using+Python%3F). Please show us your attempts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this library `openpyxl`. It supports read/write xlsx with python

Pip install : `pip install openpyxl`

> https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/

Comment: Questions as basic as this have usually been asked and answered. In such cases, the recommended course of action is to find the original question and flag / vote to close this one as a duplicate of the original. Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!